# Как разбить "умножение матрицы на вектор" на параллельные участки кода

Tags: c#, многопоточность, распараллеливание, parallel

В общем, необходимо с помощью методов класса Parallel (и для другого варианта с помощью Task) реализовать параллельный алгоритм умножения матрицы на вектор.
Уважаемые форумчане, подкиньте, пожалуйста, свои идеи, как это можно организовать.
Матрицу и вектор я считываю из файла.
Сам алгоритм умножения я написал, но как его распараллелить - не могу догадаться.
Любые идеи пригодятся!
Благодарю за внимание.

```
public static int[] matxvec(int [,] mat, int[] vec) //функция умножения матрицы на вектор
    {
         int[] res = new int[mat.GetLength(0)] ;

             for (int i = 0; i < mat.GetLength(0); i++)
             {
                 for (int j = 0; j < mat.GetLength(1); j++)
                 {
                     res[i] += mat[i, j] * vec[j];
                 }
             }

         return res;
        /*int[] res = new int[mat.GetLength(0)];
        Parallel.For(0, mat.GetLength(1), i =>
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < mat.GetLength(0); j++)
            {
                for (int k = 0; k < mat.GetLength(1); k++)
                {
                    res[i] += mat[i, k] * vec[k];
                }
            }
        });
        return res;*/
    }
```

Comment: По переменной `i`.

Comment: @Qwertiy прошу прощения,можно поточнее?

Comment: А чем, собственно, закоментированный вариант не устроил? Только лишний цикл из него удали.